# Tracking network activity for user login/logout/session timeout/session expired

Tags: python, vb.net, networking, authentication, session-timeout

We have a situation on our side where we are trying to trace the login/logout/session expiration/timeout for particular users. To explain in brief, we have certain customers who are complaining that while accessing our website, they are experiencing frequent session expiration and timeouts. We have the standard timeout setting but only few users accessing a particular website are complaining about it.

Network team believes that it might be the network (wireless network, ethernet. etc or may be even using multiple tabs) on the client side that is causing this, since we are not able to replicate it in-house. Is there is an easy way we can trace their network traffic to our website and see exact what happens when they get this timeout errors? Unfortunately, we cannot install network monitor or such tools on their end (client side) and I tried something like this before :-

```
netsh trace start capture=yes persistent=yes
netsh trace stop
```

But it is not very easy to read the NetTrace with this method. We do not believe that it is an issue with our site since other users (outside our network) can access it without any issue but only those from a particular location are experiencing this. Is there any easy functionality in VB-Script/Batch/Python to generate a kind of detailed and human readable/understandable log to trace the root cause of these frequent timeouts?

Server: Windows 7
Browser: Chrome, Firefox, IE (all upgraded to the latest version)

Comment: How are you planning on identifying just those users with the problems amongst all users anyway? You can record all packets, but analyzing all of them by hand will be a PITA.

Comment: For now.... All we know that those users from a particular location (office) are facing this intermittent timeout issues which in itself partly justifies that it is not an application issue but network issue on client side but we are looking for substantiations.

Comment: @JensHöpken Never heard of it